# Sorting JS array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following Javascript array:

```
myArr = [[["One"],["First","Fourth","Third"]], 
         [["Two"],["First","Second","Third"]], 
         [["Three"],["First","Third"]], 
         [["One two"],["Fourth","Second","Third"]], 
         [["One three"],["Fourth","Third"]], 
         [["One two three"],["Second","Third"]]];
```

I need this sorted so I get:

```
[[["One"],["First","Fourth","Third"]], 
 [["One three"],["Fourth","Third"]], 
 [["One two"],["Fourth","Second","Third"]], 
 [["One two three"],["Second","Third"]], 
 [["Three"],["First","Third"]], 
 [["Two"],["First","Second","Third"]]]
```

I assumed I could just use `myArr.sort()` and get the properly sorted array.
It does work on a flat array but not on nested arrays. When i use `myArr.sort()` I get:

```
[[["One three"],["Fourth","Third"]], 
 [["One two three"],["Second","Third"]], 
 [["One two"],["Fourth","Second","Third"]], 
 [["One"],["First","Fourth","Third"]], 
 [["Three"],["First","Third"]], 
 [["Two"],["First","Second","Third"]]]
```

This makes zero sense to me. How does JS sort get to that result? And how do I get the result I need.

Comment: Give the docs a try. It will make sense. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: _"elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order"_.  Arrays are converted to comma delimited strings.  Since space comes before comma in the Unicode sequence the elements with space separated words come first.

Comment: @david25272 thanks. That's probably the most clear explanation I have read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugly way:

```
myArr.sort((a, b) => (a[0][0]).localeCompare(b[0][0]))
```

Basically you want to compare the first element of each array to each other's

```js
myArr = [[["One"],["First","Fourth","Third"]], 
         [["Two"],["First","Second","Third"]], 
         [["Three"],["First","Third"]], 
         [["One two"],["Fourth","Second","Third"]], 
         [["One three"],["Fourth","Third"]], 
         [["One two three"],["Second","Third"]]];
         
const sorted = myArr.sort((a, b) => (a[0][0]).localeCompare(b[0][0]));

console.log(sorted);
```